# Redirect after form success symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, symfony4

I followed this tutorial: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

to build my form and it renders ok, I have a user created in my table and use its username and password to log in but get redirected to a blank page, but I've set it up to go to `/dashboard`

my security.yaml

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\User: bcrypt
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        provider:   user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            default_target_path: /dashboard
```

I even tried using the hidden `_target` input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('dashboard') }}" />
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
        {
            $error    = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            $lastUser = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('login/form.html.twig', array('last_username' => $lastUser, 'error' => $error));
        }
    }
```

full code base: https://github.com/BPSBiro/symfony-forms-errors

but it just redirects to `/login` as a blank page. I know it's not erroring (credentials wise) because if I type gibberish into both fields then it goes back to `/login` with the form and error message (invalid credentials).

How do I redirect after form success?

Comment: are you trying to put the route name?
default_target_path: 'dashboard' and always_use_default_target_path: true

Comment: check_path is behind the firewall? in my case i've not the same route for login_path and check_path. login_path is accessible for anonymous, not the check_path (and the method reached by the check_path route just contain a throw new \Exception('This should never be reached!');)

Comment: i use this https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html with a login form, you can take a look

Comment: And you are sure login is successful?  The profile bar shows an authenticated user?  Seems to me login is failing.

Comment: And the profile bar?  Not to be pushy but sometimes it appears the login was successful when it's not.  A blank page seems suspicious as well.  You are running in debug mode?

Comment: Maybe on posting the controller but having a "blank screen" does not make much sense.  Why is there no body?  You say it redirects to login but I would expect GET /login to return a page with your login form.

Comment: The tutorial works.  Consider posting your code to a github repo and I'll take a look.  Trying to debug bits and pieces can be challenging.

Comment: And as a WAG, in your login form did you use _username and _password?

Comment: @Cerad that I did :)

Comment: @Cerad https://github.com/BPSBiro/symfony-forms-errors there you go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I brought down your github and ran it unchanged.  Created a user and then tried to login.  Got an exception pointing to App\Entity\User::serialize.  You had a minor problem here:

```
public function serialize()
{
    # causes infinite nesting
    # return $this->serialize(array($this->id, $this->username, $this->password));

    # the fix
    return serialize(array($this->id, $this->username, $this->password));
}
```

The mystery is why you got a blank page instead of an exception.  I used the built in server for testing:

```
bin/console server:start
```

I'm guessing your Apache configuration is actually running in production mode which is suppressing your errors.

Comment: wabam it worked :) thank you for taking the time to look at it, I wouldn't have bee able to get there. Time to install xdebug I think haha thanks again :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with xdebug.  You should have gotten a big old exception screen when you tried to login.  You need to get that screen or else any other minor error will just give you an unhelpful blank page.

Comment: I more mean for debugging in general, and it's probably like as you said, apache is supressing errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep `http_basic: ~` if you are using traditional form login ? Please remove this and try again